# Unable to mount USB Drive

Tags: usb, mount

I have a flash drive that I received from a fried to copy files off of.  We are unable to get it to connect to any computer.  Ubuntu shows it on lsusb.

Output of lsusb

```
Device: ID 1f75:0903 Innostor Technology Corporation 
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               2.10
bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0        64
idVendor           0x1f75 Innostor Technology Corporation
idProduct          0x0903 
bcdDevice            0.01
iManufacturer           1 Innostor
iProduct                2 PenDrive
iSerial                 3 000000000000000354
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength                 9
bDescriptorType         2
wTotalLength           32
bNumInterfaces          1
bConfigurationValue     1
iConfiguration          0 
bmAttributes         0x80
  (Bus Powered)
MaxPower              200mA
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        0
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           2
  bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
  bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
  bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval               0
 Binary Object Store Descriptor:
 bLength                 5
 bDescriptorType        15
 wTotalLength           22
 bNumDeviceCaps          2
 USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
bLength                 7
bDescriptorType        16
bDevCapabilityType      2
bmAttributes   0x00000002
  Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
 bLength                10
 bDescriptorType        16
 bDevCapabilityType      3
 bmAttributes         0x00
 wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
   Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
   Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
   Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
 bFunctionalitySupport   1
   Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
  bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
  bU2DevExitLat          32 micro seconds
 Device Status:     0x0000
 (Bus Powered)
```

Thanks for the hlep!

Comment: What filesystem is the USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

"We are unable to get it to connect to any computer" sounds like the USB is pretty much dead.

But does anything show up on linux/Ubuntu from `lsblk` or `sudo blkid` or `sudo fdisk -l`? If nothing about the usb, that's a big red flag that it's dead.

What are the messages in `dmesg` or files in `/var/log/` (like `/var/log/syslog`) when it's plugged in? Should have some messages about "new usb device", then if it's able to communicate a message containing something like "/dev/sdc" (or sda, sdd, maybe hdb, hdc...) shortly after. But then it should show up with `lsblk` or `blkid`